# How can i get content from scrolling field and place it into in an array in Live code

Tags: livecode, livecoding

How can i get content from scrolling field and place content in an array in Live code. I have code for replace content in the array

```
on mouseUp
   put "" into field f1
   put "red,RED" & CR & "green,GREEN" & CR & "blue,BLUE" into myArrayToBe 
   split myArrayToBe by CR
   put the number of lines of (the keys of myArrayToBe) into myArraylength
  repeat with i = 1 to myArraylength 
   put  myArrayToBe[i] into y
   split y by comma
   put y[1] into searchStr
   put y[2] into replaceStr
   put replaceStr &CR after field f1
  end repeat
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should do the trick

```
function lines_to_array pLines
   put pLines into tArray
   split tArray by return
   RETURN tArray
end lines_to_array
```

Example

```
on mouseUp
   put lines_to_array(field "Guests") into tGuests

   -- do something with the array tGuests here
end mouseUp
```